# Illusion in maths?? (Area of sectors and segments)

Tags: circles, area

I was practising for my maths Olympiad when I stumbled upon this question...

[image: Figure]

This question is more than just a figure. It actually isn't what it looks like. I could've simply seen the solution at the back and moved further but that question stuck to me.

Yes, you would think at first that $b>a$ but $b$ is actually equal to $a$. I just want to know that why do I perceive it like that while mathematically it's untrue. I did found out the solution myself.

[image: Solution]

Comment: I can't even tell what $a$ and $b$ are supposed to be.

Comment: Should've gone to specsavers.

Comment: It looks that way because it is badly drawn.

Comment: I can't read your picture of your work.  That is what typing and MathJax are for.

Comment: @Randall I didn't get you.

Comment: It’s not clear if they are to be lengths of arcs or the enclosed areas.

Comment: Thank you for figuring it out for me...I was really thinking that these are drawn to scale although many figures in this book are not drawn to scale

Comment: @Randall they are the areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not semicircles, so the picture is simply wrong
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Paul is right. The semi circles aren't drawn to scale; they don't project far enough into the quadrant, exaggerating $b$ while shrinking $a$. (A diagram could easily do the opposite with bulging semi circles, but I suspect the effect wouldn't fool as many.) This may have been deliberate, to encourage algebra while teaching you a valuable lesson.